# Looking for functions

Tags: asymptotics, special-functions, approximation

I am looking for functions that

- have a minimum at 0 [edit: I meant f'(0)=0]
- and are asymptotically linear

I came up with $\tanh(x) x$, which is fine, but more suggestions would be welcome.
(It's needed for data-fitting.)

Thx in advance, Jo

Comment: [Logistic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) are great for modeling.  They are asymptotically constant, though of course you can multiply by $x$ if you like.  If you set the lower bound at $0$...does that do what you want?

Comment: what about : $f(x) = \lvert  ax \rvert$ $\quad a \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Try $f(x):=\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2}-\epsilon$ for $0<\epsilon\ll1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the domain in question, for example: $f: \mathbb R_{+} \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x$ works.

Otherwise, consider $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by  $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{x+1}$.

I thought of this by noticing that for positive $x$, $\frac{x^2-1}{x+1} \leq g(x) \leq \frac{x^2+1}{x+1}$.

Either way, to really see it, take $h(x)=x$ and, so 
$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{x+1}=1.$

Comment: Thx. The question-comments by @lulu and

Comment: @ChristianBlatter also work.

Answer (score 0):

> $$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad f(x)=C|x|+g(x)$$

where $\text{argmin}(g(x))=0$ and $g(x)=o(x)$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$. For example $g(x)=0,\frac{1}{1+x^2},e^{-|x|}...$

Comment: Thx, and sorry for the initially wrong formulated question ... experimentalists ...